# Unzipping large files on Android

Tags: java, android, unzip

I have a zip file that contains two files, a md5sum and a 3.5GB .img file, these are download by my app in the form of a zip file and then need to be unzipped on the device.
Currently I am using the below inner class, which is tested to be working for much smaller zip files:

```
private class UnZip extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        private String _zipFile;   
        private String _location;
        private int per = 0;

        public UnZip(String zipFile, String location) {
            _zipFile = zipFile;     
            _location = location;      
            _dirChecker("");   
        }    

        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try  {       
                ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_zipFile);
                bar.setMax(zip.size());
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);       
                ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
                ZipEntry ze = null;       
                while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                    Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());          
                    if(ze.isDirectory()) {           
                        _dirChecker(ze.getName());         
                    } else {      
                        // Here I am doing the update of my progress bar
                        Log.v("Decompress", "more " + ze.getName());          

                        per++;
                        publishProgress(per);

                        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location +ze.getName());           
                        for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {  

                            fout.write(c);           
                        }            
                        zin.closeEntry();          
                        fout.close();         
                    }                
                }       
                zin.close();    
            } catch(Exception e) {       
                Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);    
            }    
            return null;
        }    

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            bar.setProgress(per); //Since it's an inner class, Bar should be able to be called directly
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer... result) {
            Log.i("UnZip" ,"Completed. Total size: "+result);
        }

        private void _dirChecker(String dir) {     
            File f = new File(_location + dir);      
            if(!f.isDirectory()) {       
                f.mkdirs();     
            }   
        }

    }
```

This works well and shows the progress bar as each file is unzipped, however this takes a VERY long time for large files (About 20MB per hour on my Nexus 4).
I wanted see if there is a better method to unzip such a large file? (the .img file is actually only about 1GB of data, the rest is just trailing zeros to allow room for more data later)

Or perhaps a way to see the progress not per file but actually per MB of data, or the write speed etc? In the long run giving the user more information about how the unzip is going will be very useful.

Comment: `for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read())` reads byte by byte, read into a ~4-32k sized `byte[]`. Then write the whole buffer at once.

Comment: Could you provide sample code @zapl I assume this will speed up the extraction? seems it is doing the job but so far its done 60MB in 3 hours :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following somewhere:

```
public static void streamCopy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024]; // play with sizes..
    int readCount;
    while ((readCount = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
}
```

It's a universally useful standard code to copy inputstreams to outputstreams and found in several libraries as well.

Then use that inside your code

```
} else {
    // Here I am doing the update of my progress bar
    Log.v("Decompress", "more " + ze.getName());

    per++;
    publishProgress(per);

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());

    streamCopy(zin, fout);

    zin.closeEntry();
    fout.close();
}
```

Advantage is that you read and write in larger chunks instead of single bytes and that speeds up the process by a lot.

Comment: Perfect! unzip now takes <10 minutes!!

Comment: @ZacPowell 3.5GB in < 10 minutes would mean you get a throughput of ~6MB/s which sounds like it's close to what Android devices are capable of. Internal storage has max write speed of around 10-20MB/s - but since you read and unzip before you can write the data you won't reach that.